# Mapping laptop's keys

Tags: keyboard, mapping, key, directx

One of my laptops arrow key is not functioning, is there any way to map some other key on my keyboard to malfunctioning arrow key. I tried registry hack but it doesn't works while playing games which I suppose is due to the DirectX that games use for direct access to hardware, bypassing OS APIs (regestry etc). Many games allows you to reconfigure your controls but the one I am playing (MEAT BOY) doesn't allows me to change default controls.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665)? I think this should translate the keys at a sufficiently low level for your purposes.